# Force the usage of path aliases

Tags: nodes, uri

The title is explaining what I'm trying, my question is: Am I doing it right?

```
function hook_entity_view($entity, $type) {
    if (arg(0)=='node') {
        drupal_goto($entity->type.'/'.$entity->nid);
    }
}
```

My aliases look like this: `article/123`

- `article` is the entity type.
- `123` is the node ID.

When I go to ../node/123 than I get a 503.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are creating loop redirection. But that you can test by examining logs. I believe there is an easier way: already implemented [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module:

> This module uses hook_init to interrupt the page load and action the alias lookups. If any of the above rules apply then the appropriate action is taken. If no rules apply then the page load continues uninterrupted. An example of this in use is on the site it was developed for. http://www.sportbusiness.com/node/160559 will redirect to http://www.sportbusiness.com/news/160559/lagardere-sets-up-sports-division due to the alias setup on this site.

Comment: It does more but basically the same as what I already had. When visiting `node/123` again (with Global Redirect enabled), than it results in the same error "The page does not refer in a proper way".

Comment: @Fleuv If you have some kind of referer-based security turned on, you can expect funny results. Referer http header is optional and should never be used to actually decide anything - and your site seems to be doing exactly that.